# Determine if a Class implements an Interface without referencing it

Tags: c#, interface

I feel like this should be very possible.

I have an interface, let's call it `IJerry`. Now, I have a class in variable `x`. That class implements `IJerry` perfectly. The thing is, that class does not ever reference `IJerry`. It just *happens* to have a perfect, compliant signature with `IJerry`.

Make sense? Let's say you create a class called `MyClass` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then you delete the `MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged` declaration from the class but you LEAVE the implementation inside the class.

Is there a way to determine if the class "implements" an interface even if it does not make an explicit reference to it?

Comment: C# does not support duck typing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: @Kirk, check the information contained in your link.

Comment: @Anthony, oh, I see.  The article mentions use of **dynamic** keyword as a substitute.  IMO, that's not "duck typing" as it provides no means to operate generically on the "class" of types that satisfy that contract.  It just allows you to "try" to invoke the method if it's there.

Comment: I can't accept answers that aren't the solution or answer. But I see your point, I will review them again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not easily.

You would have to read the fields, method, and properties of the interface using reflection, and then check if the class has them (again using reflection)

Alternately, if you are using C#4, you could just forget about IJerry, and put MyClass in a dynamic variable, and then you C# figure out at run-time for it has the methods being called.

Comment: Darn. I was hoping it was possible.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot more to implementing an interface than meets the eye.  For one, implementation methods are virtual, even though you don't use that keyword.  In fact, you're not allowed to use that keyword.  For another, the compiler rearranges the methods to match the method table layout of the interface.  Removing the inherited interface from the declaration is *guaranteed* to make the result incompatible.  The methods won't be virtual anymore.

What you are pursuing is called 'dynamic dispatch'.  Implemented in the DLR and integrated into .NET 4.0 and the C# 4.0 language.  Re-inventing the System.Reflection code and making it efficient is a major undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use reflection to see if x had methods that matched the ones on IJerry.  The real question is, what are you going to do with the answer?  Prior to version 4, C# doesn't support "duck typing", so in order to use your class where an IJerry is required you have to write adapter code.

Comment: C# 4 can do dynamic typing. The reflected methods can also be invoked.